# How can I have Google Spreadsheets calculate certain cells in increments?

Tags: google-sheets

My group has a point system where three points will amount to one strike. In column F all points are totalled, and each row is a different person. How do I have Google Sheets calculate the amount of strikes each individual has?

Answer (score 1):

Just simply divide each number by the value of your increment, then round down to the nearest whole number.

```
=ROUNDDOWN(F1/3)
```

[image: screen shot of Google Sheet, with sample data and formula shown]

[Google Support: ROUNDDOWN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093442)